# Whats the most efficient way to persist a Joda-Time `DateTime` object?

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime

I've written some Java software that very frequently persists and retrieves [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects from Redis.  I just serialise and deserialise the objects at present.  The software reads the objects about 50 times more often than it writes.  I've not profiled serialising/deserialising Joda-Time objects, but the software has scaled well, computationally, under load and I'm happy with the performance.

What hasn't scaled well is memory usage.  The serialised Joda-Time objects are pretty big and a decent size Redis instance can only take about 3 days worth of customer data before I need to flush it out to a relational database on disk.  A secondary issue is Redis' own backup mechanisms seem harder to manage the larger the dataset gets...

Setting aside the temptation to throw more RAM at the problem, I've thought of the following ideas so far:

- serialise then compress the objects before persisting
- persist as a ISO date format string
- persist as some other Joda-compatible string format

I will try out and profile these before deciding, but I wonder if anyone can think of a more efficient way of reducing the memory footprint of persisted Joda objects without breaking the computational bank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ISO 8601

While I know nothing of Redis… Generally speaking, the easiest and most efficient way to serialize Joda-Time objects is to take advantage of their built-in support for the sensible, unambiguous, standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string formats for date-time values.

For a zoned date-time value, the standard provides a `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS±HH:SS` format such as `2014-10-24T21:17:30+02:00` or `2014-10-24T19:17:30Z` (`Z` for `Zulu` means an offset of 00:00 from [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

The various Joda-Time 2.5 classes use ISO 8601 as their defaults for parsing and generating String representations of date-time values.

### Generating Strings

For `DateTime`, simply call its [`toString`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString()) method either explicitly or implicitly.

```
String output = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).toString();
```

Generally best to work with UTC when storing date-time values. Joda-Time lets you easily adjust to UTC.

```
DateTime nowMontreal = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime nowUtc = nowMontreal.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
String output = nowUtc.toString();
```

Another example.

```
DateTime output = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```

### Parsing Strings

Parsing is just as easy. The only issue is time zone. If you omit a time zone, generally Joda-Time will assign the JVM’s current default time zone. Usually better if you explicitly specify the desired time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeMontreal = new DateTime( "2014-10-24T19:17:30Z", DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

or, for UTC…

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( "2014-10-24T19:17:30Z", DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

## java.time

Another alternative is the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8. Inspired by Joda-Time, java.time is similar in many ways. But one difference is that java.time by default generates string representations by extending the ISO 8601 standard to append the name of the time zone. While standard format has an offset-from-UTC, you loose the actual time zone information. (A time zone is an offset *plus* the rules for Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies in the present, future, and past.)

On the other hand, generally it is best to store date-time in UTC. If you really care about the time zone at the time of data-entry, it’s generally best to store that information separately in addition to the UTC-adjusted value.

In java.time, the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-10-24T19:17:30Z" );
String outputInstant = instant.toString();
```

> 2014-10-24T19:17:30Z

To adjust into a time zone, specify a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
String outputZdt = zdt.toString();
```

> 2014-10-24T15:17:30-04:00[America/Montreal]

Comment: Basil, thanks for the detailed answer and the idea to use the JSR 310 classes in Java 8.  As promised, I'll profile all these ideas the select the correct answer based on my testing.

Comment: wait... where did the last year go ?  sorry it took so long to accept this answer.  Having finally got round to testing serialisation vs ISO strings of joda DateTime and java.time ZonedDateTime objects to/from a Redis database, ISO 8601 wins.  ISO format is usually the same speed writing (and a heck of a lot smaller) than serialisation of objects, when storing in Redis.  Reading back from Redis (which my application is heavy on) is about 50% faster than serialisation.   Interestingly, the difference between joda and java.time seems negligible, at least in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyze a distribution of your date-time objects. If it happens that they are relatively close to each other, then you can do some "magic":

1) you can introduce a special "starting point date" constant and then store the actual date as a number of days shift from the constant - that would be integer value (~8 bytes on 64bit arch. w/o compression)

2) do you need actual time? if no - just throw away time; if yes - you can store hours+minutes+seconds in one int variable (another ~8 bytes on 64bit arch. w/o compression)

3) analyze results - there is a chance that you could fit both: the date (shift) and the time in a single int variable

4) introduce a caching mechanism, that would greatly increase performance of serializing/deserializing your objects

Comment: Ivan, thanks for your answer and great idea on using int offsets.  The application is distributed so local caching is probably out of the question (redis is the cache).  Will test this idea and mark the correct answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Store the millis since the start of the epoch. It is a single long value. If you need a timezoned value also store timezone Id as a string. Serializing and parsing the string representation will always take more resources including RAM, there so much data processing  inside, some regex, split calls which allocates more memory.

Use this constructor for restoring the value: `public BaseDateTime(long instant, DateTimeZone zone)`
It is so light waight because it is stores rightaway what is under the hood of every DateTime instance:

```
public BaseDateTime(long instant, Chronology chronology) {
        super();
        iChronology = checkChronology(chronology);
        iMillis = checkInstant(instant, iChronology);
        adjustForMinMax();
}
```